# PHP, MYSQL select box not selecting correctly

Tags: php, javascript

Got another wierd one:

Here is my php:

```
echo "</tr><tr>";
echo "<td style='color:white;'>".$row['iDesc']."</td><td>".$row['pCnt']."</td><td style='color:".$color.";'>".$row['pDur']."</td><td>".$row['pStr']."</td><td>".$row['pSpd']."</td><td>";
echo "<select name='wield".$row['pNum']."' id='wield".$row['pNum']."' size='1' style='width: 100px;' onChange='wieldit(".$row['pNum'].");'>";
echo "<option value=0>Use On";
$query = "Select item, iDesc from item where iType = 1";
$result2 = mysql_query($query, $_SESSION['connect']);
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
  echo "<option";
  echo " value=".$row2['item'].">".$row2['iDesc']."</option>";
}
echo "</select></td>";
}
```

Here is my js:

```
function wieldit(num) {
    var id = "wield"+num;
    var e = $(id); 
    var t =  e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var params = "sWield="+t;
    params += "&sNum="+num;
    new Ajax.Updater('div06', 'php/pack.php', {method: 'get', parameters: params, onComplete: showBody});
}
```

When I run it the values in the select box are 0, 1, 2, 26, 25,24, 23, 31. For the example I'm running $row['pNum'] = 6 and I'm selecting select value 31. When I do alert on params in the js sWield = 0 and sNum = 6. The thing is, sWield should be 31. Ideas?. If I run with different values, say $row['pNum'] = 11 and select value 25 in the js sWield = 25 and sNum is 11 the way it should be. Ideas?

Comment: Please show the resulting HTML that is rendered by PHP.

Comment: do the weird results you get match up with the database?

Comment: Is the HTML output from your PHP code assigning values correctly in the <select> element? Seems to me that the value= of `$row['pNum'] = 6` is not being passed to the wieldit() function

Comment: The results match up with the database. I don't know how to show the resulting html. I'm using ajax and the only html the shows rendered is my index page with the standard divs I set up. It's the sWield being 0 that's the problem.

Comment: Ok, I could view the rendered html and it looks fine. I'd send it in the comment but it won't let me so it can be seen at this link: [link](http://hand.seestes.com/problem5.txt)

Comment: unrelated... try not to echo anything that doesn't need to be compiled by PHP. Example, replace `echo "</tr><tr>";` with `</tr><tr>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value 31 is the 7th option in your selectbox.
As Javascript starts counting from 0, it's displaying 6.

So it seems it alerts the index in stead of the chosen value.
You could try to try this, and put quotes around the value:
`<option value='31'>Arms</option>`

Answer (score 3):

You are not closing the first option
`echo "<option value=0>Use On</option>";`

Try closing this one first!

Comment: most browsers can deal with that no problem (same with <li>), always best to close though.